# sqlite datatype for storing decimals

Tags: sqlite, floating-point, decimal, sqldatatypes

I would like to store cryptocurrency financial data in `sqlite`, but am not able to figure out how the precision of the numbers is handled.. The crypto precision/scale could go as low as 8 digits, and the real number part to 10-12 digits. I.e. following number is possible: `123456789111.12345678`

If we init a table with a record:

```sql
PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;

PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;

CREATE TABLE datas ( 
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    price decimal NOT NULL
);

insert into datas (price) values (123456789111.12345678);
```

then the inserted record will be rounded to `123456789111.12346`.

`123456789111.12346` is only **a 16 digit number. The input was a 20 digit number.** Why does the `sqlite` is only storing 16 digits?

I am planning on using it with the `C#`, where `decimal`s could be up to **28 digits long**. The 16 digits actually correlate with the `double` datatype, not a `decimal`, according to `C#` [datatypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types).

What I have tried doing is setting the column type to `REAL`, `CURRENCY`, `DECIMAL`, `DECIMAL(28,8)`, `MONEY`, nothing seems to work.. I know for sure that other databases such as sqlserver are able to handle decimals just fine.. So perhaps there is something I am missing with the sqlite?

using `sqlite version 3.43.2`

I am sorry if the question has been answered someplace. I was not able to find the exact answer on `stackoverflow`. Most of the answers/questions were 10 years old, but if I am wrong please point me to the right direction :) thank you.

Comment: https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html is necessary reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While unintuitive, the only way around this I've found is to just store the full decimal number as datatype `TEXT` and parse it back to a decimal in code. As you mentioned, `DECIMAL` only has 16 digit precision. `TEXT` will allow you to store numbers as strings with much higher precision.

Comment: it seems like dapper has a support for the TEXT field out of the box. Meaning I did not need to write a separate TEXT to NUMBER converter when reading the data from/to DB.. quite convenient. Thank you for help. I ended up using the text field as per your suggestion.